# What is the difference between USART and SPI communication?

Tags: microcontroller, communication, spi, usart

While reading about USART peripheral in STM32 bluepill, I realized that USART is similar to SPI. I have searched for the differences but I don't find any.

Please, clearly explain the need for these two different protocols.

Comment: Look up USART, very very easy to find a description. it is a generic term for a possibly overcomplicated logic block that handles multiple low speed serial protocols like SDLC, HDLC, SPI, UART, I2C and others.  Not all USARTs handle all those protocols and it depends on the vendor as to whether they bother to use that term.  ST could have just shown UART, SPI, and I2C registers without using that term.  sometimes it is used just to describe a fancy UART with sync or async capabilities.

Comment: if you are asking the difference between UART and SPI that is even easier to find, clearly different protocols. NEEDing different protocols is because over decades they have been created and some devices support one, some devices support another and an mcu worth buying will support a number of protocols in hardware

Answer (score -1):

The most important differences are

1. SPI can be faster than USART
2. SPI can have multi slave